# Socket programming - long connection mode

Tags: sockets

As the picture shows,when in the long connection mode,the server recv and send,the client send and recv.And my question is:

- Can I only just use the send in the client and just use the recv in the server?

The test code:
The server:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    WORD sockVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(sockVersion, &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }


    SOCKET slisten = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (slisten == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("socket error !");
        return 0;
    }


    sockaddr_in sin;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(8888);
    sin.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;//
    if (bind(slisten, (LPSOCKADDR)&sin, sizeof(sin)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind error !");
    }


    if (listen(slisten, 30) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("listen error !");
        return 0;
    }


    SOCKET sClient;
    sockaddr_in remoteAddr;
    int nAddrlen = sizeof(remoteAddr);
    char revData[255];
    while (true)
    {
        printf("waitting...\n");
        sClient = accept(slisten, (SOCKADDR *)&remoteAddr, &nAddrlen);
        if (sClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("accept error !");
            continue;
        }
        printf("receive a connection：%s \r\n", inet_ntoa(remoteAddr.sin_addr));
        char * sendData = "R\n";
        //
        while (1)
        {
            int ret = recv(sClient, revData, 255, 0);
            if (ret > 0)
            {
                revData[ret] = 0x00;
                printf(revData);
                //new add code
                //send(sClient, sendData, strlen(sendData), 0);

            }
            else
                break;
        }





        closesocket(sClient);
    }

    closesocket(slisten);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The client:

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <WINSOCK2.H>
#include <STDIO.H>

#pragma  comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WORD sockVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    WSADATA data;
    if (WSAStartup(sockVersion, &data) != 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    SOCKET sclient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sclient == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("invalid socket !");
        return 0;
    }

    sockaddr_in serAddr;
    serAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serAddr.sin_port = htons(8888);
    serAddr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("10.92.1.148");
    if (connect(sclient, (sockaddr *)&serAddr, sizeof(serAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("connect error !");
        closesocket(sclient);
        return 0;
    }
    char * sendData = "T\n";
    int cnt = 0;
    char recData[255];
    while (1)
    {

        send(sclient, sendData, strlen(sendData), 0);

        //new add code
        //int ret = recv(sclient, recData, 255, 0);
        //if (ret > 0)
        //{
        //  recData[ret] = 0x00;
        //  printf(recData);
        //}
    }
    printf("cnt=%d\n",cnt);



    closesocket(sclient);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is wrong when I test.While when I add the new code,the program can run.The new code is the code after the // as the above .So I think just have send in one side and recv in another side maybe wrong.It have to have a loop.Is it right?Must I have a loop(request and response loop in the picture)?

Comment: I don't see any pictures. Can you reupload it?

Comment: Thank you.I have upload it?Can you see it?

Comment: My question is :After the accept,can the client just use the send,like this: send...send ....send...,and the server just use the recv,like this: recv...recv...recv...Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you have control over the software on the client and the server, you can do whatever patterns of send() and recv() you want on either side.

Comment: Thank you so much.I just want to use the send() in the client and the recv() in the server.Don't have the" Request and Response loop" in the picture.Is it ok?Just like this:                                                                                          in the client:the fake code maybe while(1){send()};in the server:the fake code maybe  while(1){recv()}.Is it ok?

Comment: This is the first time I use the stackoverflow.Can someone tell me how to upload the code?Maybe the question is more explicit.

Comment: You can paste the code in the body of the question. Put 4 spaces before every line and the code will be styled so it is easier to read.